# Tools for creating android UI theme

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, themes

I've look all over and i didn't find any good tool that could help me to create themes for my application.
Not that o don;t need to create layouts, but to customize appearance of existing layouts.
Ideal would be a tool that would load layouts from my android application and work on them, but it would me more than sufficient to work on some demo layouts.

Maybe something similar as this web tool http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/?ver=1.1.0&style_id=20120622-116
It would be nice to have predefined themes.

Do you know such a tool ?
10x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) has many useful tools, especially the Holo editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can get pretty decently designed icons and PSD templates [here](http://speckyboy.com/2010/09/30/60-psd-icon-and-button-templates)